# Jest mocked class force different response, typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

this is me again with very simple example.
In resumen i need a different response for the mocked class.

This is my simple class that return an object

```
            class Producer {
                hello() {
                    return {
                        message:'Class: Hello',
                    }
                }
            }
            export default Producer;
```

this is the mock class in the `__mocks__` folder

```
            class Producer {
                hello() {
                    return {
                        message:'__mocks__: hello',
                    }
                }
            }
            export default Producer;
```

This is my test file that works as i expected

```
            import Consumer from './Consumer';
            jest.mock('./Producer');
            test('simple test 1', () => {
                let consumer = new Consumer();
                consumer.call();
                expect(consumer.response.message).toEqual('__mocks__: hello')
                console.log(consumer.response)
                // prints on console { message: '__mocks__: hello' }
            });
```

My question is, for other test i need a different response from the mocked file `Producer`

```
            jest.mock('./Producer').updateOnTheFly( hello() { 
                    return {
                        message:'UPDATE ON FLY: hello',
                    }
            })
            test('simple test 1', () => {

                let consumer = new Consumer();
                consumer.call();
                expect(consumer.response.message).toEqual('UPDATE ON FLY: hello')
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

For something like this it can be easier to *not* create a manual mock at `__mocks__/Producer.js`.

Instead, use `jest.mock('./Producer');` to auto-mock the module...

...then mock the return value for `Producer.prototype.hello` as needed:

```
import Consumer from './Consumer';

import Producer from './Producer';
jest.mock('./Producer');  // <= auto-mock Producer

test('simple test 1', () => {
  Producer.prototype.hello.mockReturnValue({ message: 'mocked: hello' });
  let consumer = new Consumer();
  consumer.call();
  expect(consumer.response.message).toEqual('mocked: hello')  // Success!
});

test('simple test 2', () => {
  Producer.prototype.hello.mockReturnValue({ message: 'UPDATED: hello' });
  let consumer = new Consumer();
  consumer.call();
  expect(consumer.response.message).toEqual('UPDATED: hello')  // Success!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some re-search i resolved with this.

```
        class Producer {
            hello() {
                return {
                    message:' Class: Hello ',
                }
            }
        }
        export default Producer;
```

Mocking the `Producer`, it is not neccesary create **mock** file

```
        import Consumer from './Consumer';
        jest.mock('./Producer');

        test('simple test 1', () => {
            // mocking Producer.hello()
            Producer.mockImplementation(() => {
                return {
                    hello: () => {
                        return {
                            message: "ths is mocked "
                        }
                    },
                };
            });  

            let consumer = new Consumer();
            consumer.call(); /// Consume.call() uses inside Producer.hello() mocked
        })
```